# Getting user's current location but getting back "Optional" California.. etc

Tags: ios, swift, location

I'm trying to get the user's current location using Swift. Here is what I am currently using:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager();

    //Info about user
    @IBOutlet weak var userTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var BarbCustTF: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation();

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    // GPS STUFF
    // UPDATE LOCATION
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!) { (placemarks, ErrorType) -> Void in
            if(ErrorType != nil)
            {
                print("Error: " + ErrorType!.localizedDescription);
                return;
            }

            if(placemarks?.count > 0)
            {
                let pm = placemarks![0] ;
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm);
            }
        }
    }

    // STOP UPDATING LOCATION
    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark)
    {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation();
        print(placemark.locality);
        print(placemark.postalCode);
        print(placemark.administrativeArea);
        print(placemark.country);
    }

    // PRINT OUT ANY ERROR WITH LOCATION MANAGER
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription);
    }
```

Everything seems to work fine, but the output I'm getting is like really weird and says Optional in front of it, and is definitely (unfortunately) not my current location.

This is the output I'm getting when I print it to the console

**Optional("Cupertino")**

**Optional("95014")**

**Optional("CA")**

**Optional("United States")**

Things I've tried:
1) In my info.plist I have : `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`
2) I've also heard weird stuff happens and I tried going to *Debug>>Location>>* and changing it to in city and all sorts of things (didn't help)

I think that the problem is something in my function `LocationManager` that has to do with like "wrapping" or something ? I'm not sure, this is my first day messing with iOS programming with Swift and I don't really know what wrapping is but I think that may be what's going on from what I've seen on the internet... Basically I dont understand why i'm printing out some default apple locations (California.. blah blah) I don't live in Cali (unfortunately).

Comment: The `Optional(...)` is because your printing a `Optional` that's enclosing a `String`. You need to unwrap the optional to get the underlying type using `if let` or `!`.

Comment: paul, how do I do that?

Comment: Are you running this on the simulator? If so, I would try to run your app on a physical device and see if it gives you the correct output.

Comment: To get the correct location in the simulator, go to Debug > Location > Custom Location, and set your desired latitude and longitude.

Comment: Simulator @tfrank377

Comment: @paulvs Why would i hardcode the lat & long, the whole point is for the program to figure that out right?

Comment: @paulvs how do I implement what you were originally saying with the if let or ! thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
print(placemark.locality);
```

do this

```
if let locality = placemark.locality {
    print(locality)
}
```

The `if let` pattern here is a way of only printing `locality` if it's not `nil`. This is the way to do it in this case.

If you were sure that `locality` was never `nil`, you could do

```
print(placemark.locality!)
```

but if `locality` happened to be `nil`, your app would crash on that line.

Comment: Paul the Optional is now gone, but why is it printing Cupertiono? Why does it not know that I am in Virginia?

Comment: It's like defaulting something instead of getting the location where I am at

Comment: Since your running on the simulator, there is no real GPS. So you have to set the location manually (Debug > Location > Custom Location).

Comment: Oh i see, now it makes sense why you said that LOL

Comment: Also paul, do you know why sometimes it ask for location services and sometimes it doesn't when i run the simulator? Is that just a simulator thing?

Comment: it asks to "enable them" more so

Comment: When you first run the app in a simulator, it asks for permission. On subsequent runs, it has the permission saved so it doesn't ask again. If you reset the simulator however, and run the app again, it will ask for permission again.

Comment: By resetting the simulator - you mean exiting out of xcode completely and restarting right?

Comment: Or is there a specific button I should click to reset the simulator?

Comment: With the simulator open, go to Simulator > Reset Content and Settings

Comment: Your a lifesaver paul